# Getting Duplicate Rows when inserting in MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am scrapping data from a static page (It does not change) using Beautiful Soup in Python. But when I parse the required information(usernames) and store in db, I find some usernames missing, while some usernames duplicated. This does not happen always. I dont understand why it happens. There are about 25 pages with 100 usernames in each. Here is the structure of the overall code.

```
    url = "someurl.com"
    for id in 1 to 25
        page=urllib2.urlopen(url + str(id))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        #parse and make data to insert here
        for all usernames in page
            sql = "create table if not exists table" 
            cursor.execute(sql)
            sql = "insert into table username"
            cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
```

This is the rough code. There are about 2500-3000 usernames in the table. And about 20 are repeated, i.e. say username = "XYZ" is absent whereas username = "ABC" is repeated twice.

Could anyone suggest why it happens and what is the fix ?

Comment: I don't think it is happening anywhere in the snippet provided. Can you expand upon the `#parse and make data to insert here` part?

Comment: @mu無 : I am sure there is nothing wrong in that. It is like <code>for string in data[1].stripped_strings: username = string</code> + more statements like that. Does that happen because the cursor is executing one of the insertions, while the python thread loops over to the next username ? There are quite a lot of insertions. About 12 fields per insertion. And as I said, this does not happen always. If this is the reason, is there a way to maintain atomicity. ?

Comment: @mattgiltaji: Obviously there are no duplicates in the static pages. I dont want to check for duplicates before insertion. I want to know why it is happening and how to fix it because I am losing some data because of dupicates.

Comment: @user3215014 One possible reason could be the names having a space or other whitespace, which causes similar usernames to be re-inserted, because the parsing logic only checks for the first word in the username. Example: `user name1` `user name2` both get inserted as `user`.

Comment: Other than the above *possible* reason, can't think of other reasons without more info about the parsing logic and the input values which are getting inserted not at all/ multiple times.

Comment: what happens if you print the usernames in the "for all usernames in page" step -- are there duplicates? If so, the parsing has issues.  Parsing is hard...